# capture instances of a column value where its seen more than once

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
id_1   id_2 id_3    id_4    id_5    
0133    11   kelly  AA-1    1        
2119    22   Wade   AA-2    1        
3903    33   John   BB-1    1        
3903    33   John   BB-2    1        
3903    33   John   BB-3    1        
5133    44   Emily  C-1     1               
9148    99   Pete   BB-34   1       
9148    99   Pete   BB-23   1        
2910    111  Mark   DD-3    1
```

I want to iterate through it and capture any instace where the id_1 has the same value when its greater than 1.

I want to only capture colums id_4 and id_5. This will ultimately be added to a JSON object so the end result would be:

```
{"id_1": "0133", "id_2": "11", "id_3": "kelly", "items": [{"id_4":"AA-1", "id_5":"1"}]}
{"id_1": "2119", "id_2": "22", "id_3": "Wade", "items": [{"id_4":"AA-2", "id_5":"1"}]}
{"id_1": "3903", "id_2": "33", "id_3": "John", "items": [{"id_4":"BB-1", "id_5":"1",{"id_4":"BB-1", "BB-2":"1"}, ,{"id_4":"BB-1", "BB-3":"1"}]}
{"id_1": "5133", "id_2": "44", "id_3": "Emily", "items": [{"id_4":"C-1", "id_5":"1"}]}
{"id_1": "9148", "id_2": "99", "id_3": "Pete", "items": [{"id_4":"BB-34", "id_5":"1",{"id_4":"BB-23", "BB-2":"1"}]}
{"id_1": "2910", "id_2": "111", "id_3": "Mark", "items": [{"id_4":"DD-3", "id_5":"1"}]}
```

Would anyone know the best approach to accomplish something like this? any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
df.groupby('id_1').nth(1).reset_index()[['id_4','id_5']]
```

Then you can convert it to JSON.

Comment: I understand you're grouping by id_1 but how do I relate the output of this to id_1 when I build out my JSON? In order words, how would I link back "id_1": "3903", "id_2": "33", "id_3": "John" TO "items": [{"id_4":"BB-1", "id_5":"1",{"id_4":"BB-1", "BB-2":"1"}, ,{"id_4":"BB-1", "BB-3":"1"}]} @Phoenix